How to Retrieve Session ID After Successful Authentication in Odoo JSON-RPC for Invoice Creation?
I am developing a PHP script to integrate with Odoo using JSON-RPC. The goal is to authenticate a user and then create a custom invoice in the Odoo database. The authentication process successfully returns the user ID (uid), but the session ID (session_id) is coming back as empty. Without the session ID, subsequent requests (e.g., to create the invoice) fail due to session expiration.
function odoo_jsonrpc($url, $method, $params, $session_id = null) {
    $data = array(
        "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
        "method" => $method,
        "params" => $params,
        "id" => rand(1, 1000000),
    );

    $data_string = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array_filter([
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            $session_id ? 'Cookie: session_id=' . $session_id : null,
        ]),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($response, true);
}

// 1. Authenticate
$auth_params = [
    "db" => $db_name,
    "login" => $username,
    "password" => $password,
];

$auth_result = odoo_jsonrpc($url . '/web/session/authenticate', 'call', $auth_params);

if (!$auth_result || isset($auth_result['error'])) {
    die("Authentication error: " . json_encode($auth_result));
}

$uid = $auth_result['result']['uid'];
$session_id = $auth_result['result']['session_id'];
echo "Authenticated with UID: $uid, Session ID: $session_id\n";

// 2. Create Invoice
$invoice_data = [
    'name' => uniqid('INV-'),
    'partner_id' => 9, // Replace with your partner ID
    'user_id' => 2,    // Replace with your User ID
    'invoice_line_ids' => [[0, 0, [
        'name' => 'Product 1',
        'quantity' => rand(1, 5),
        'price_unit' => rand(10, 100),
        'account_id' => 1, // Replace with your account ID
        'product_id' => 1, // Replace with your product ID
    ]]],
    'move_type' => 'out_invoice',
];

$create_params = [
    'model' => 'account.move',
    'method' => 'create',
    'args' => [$invoice_data],
];

$create_result = odoo_jsonrpc($url . '/web/dataset/call_kw', 'call', $create_params, $session_id);

if (!$create_result || isset($create_result['error'])) {
    die("Invoice creation error: " . json_encode($create_result));
}

$invoice_id = $create_result['result'];
echo "Invoice created with ID: " . $invoice_id . "\n";


Problem - I have verified that the db, login, and password variables are correct. The response successfully returns the uid, so authentication seems to work partially.
Shortest way to replicate my problem - make a demo account in odoo and add a database and invoicing app in database then with your credentials run this code

function odoo_jsonrpc($url, $method, $params, $session_id = null) {
    $data = array(
        "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
        "method" => $method,
        "params" => $params,
        "id" => rand(1, 1000000),
    );

    $data_string = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array_filter([
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            $session_id ? 'Cookie: session_id=' . $session_id : null,
        ]),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($response, true);
}

// 1. Authenticate
$auth_params = [
    "db" => $db_name,
    "login" => $username,
    "password" => $password,
];

$auth_result = odoo_jsonrpc($url . '/web/session/authenticate', 'call', $auth_params);

if (!$auth_result || isset($auth_result['error'])) {
    die("Authentication error: " . json_encode($auth_result));
}

$uid = $auth_result['result']['uid'];
$session_id = $auth_result['result']['session_id'];
echo "Authenticated with UID: $uid, Session ID: $session_id\n";


I tried finding logs in odoo web interface which i could not find , verified credentials to see if that is causing the issue
